# Crystal Reports Else If statement

Tags: if-statement, crystal-reports

I can't figure out why this if statement won't work.
I have a DateTime field DATEFROM and a String parameter (it HAS to be String) periodEnd.
I would like to calculate percentages depending if these two dates have 1, 2, 3 or more years difference. 
When I use this formula I get either "100%" or "-" and never the other two options. It's like CR calculates the first IF and if it's true then: "100%" but if it's false, it never checks for the rest of the Else Ifs and goes dirreclty to Else

```
StringVar percentage:="";
If (cDate({?periodEnd})-{TABLE.DATEFROM})<=1 Then 
    percentage:="100%"
Else If (cDate({?periodEnd})-{TABLE.DATEFROM})<=2 Then 
    percentage:="66%"
Else If (cDate({?periodEnd})-{TABLE.DATEFROM})<=3 Then 
    percentage:="33%"
Else 
    percentage:="-"
```

Any idea?

Comment: Approach wrong....what are subtracting exactly....year or month or day...what is your eequirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) I assume you already made sure your `periodend` format matches with what `cdate` interprets?
If you just subtract them, Crystal by default returns the number of days between.
Two ways you can do year:

```
datediff("yyyy",cDate({?periodEnd},{TABLE.DATEFROM})
```

or

```
year(cDate({?periodEnd})-year({TABLE.DATEFROM})
```

b) You've also no doubt accounted for when your `{TABLE.DATEFROM}` is greater than `cDate({?periodEnd}` and you have a negative result?
Not sure if the following is the behavior you would want, but I'm throwing it in for your information

```
ABS(datediff("yyyy",cDate({?periodEnd},{TABLE.DATEFROM}))
```

**make sure you check the help file for the datediff codes ("yyyy" etc) as they are not *quite* instinctive and can trip you up when you think you're using the obvious one

Comment: Thank you! I tryied the DateDiff function. Umm.. If it's no much trouble can you tell me how I can check the format of a the variable "periodend"? My dates are "DD/MM/YYYY" and I just typed a date with the same format for my variable.

Comment: No sure what you mean... You could simply putting in the body of the report and running the report would show it.  For sanity when my head can't interpret help files I've been known to put it as is, and then next to it the result after the cdate (or whatever you are using) conversion so I can see what misunderstandings are happening (make sure you check at least one where the day is more than 13 so you are absolutely sure.  Also could display a formula `totext(year(cdate({?periodEnd})),0)+"/"+totext(month(cdate({?periodEnd}))),0)+"/"+totext(day(cdate({?periodEnd}))),0)`.